# I invoke LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL() using C++, but get a segment fault

Tags: c++, macos

I want to write a C++ program to get associated applications which are suitable to open specified file. I find the LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL API, and create a command line C++ application by XCode.

But after running this program, I always get segment fault. XCode shows EXEC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address....) error.

I also tryied running it from sudo, but the same result. What is the problem?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <objc/objc.h>
#include <objc/objc-runtime.h>
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <CoreServices/CoreServices.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    auto url = CFURLRef("file:///Users/efan/src/a.cpp");
    auto ret = LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(url, kLSRolesAll);
    cout << ret << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your `CFURLRef` using one of the proper `CFURLCreate*` methods. See "Creating a CFURL" [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfurl?language=objc).

For example:

```
auto tempStringURL = CFStringCreateWithCString(nullptr, "/Users/efan/src/a.cpp", kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
auto url = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(nullptr, tempStringURL, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, FALSE);
auto ret = LSCopyApplicationURLsForURL(url, kLSRolesAll);
```

You need to `Release` the "Created" variables to clean up memory.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly the point. I used CFSTR("/Users/efan/src/a.cpp"), Do I still need to release the string?

Comment: You may, but you don't have to. The string will remain valid for the lifetime of the program.